# How to split negative and positive values in string using php?

Tags: php, regex

I have a string variable in php, with look like "`0+1.65+0.002-23.9`", and I want to split in their individual values.

Ex:

```
 0
1.65
0.002
-23.9
```

I Try to do with:

```
$keys = preg_split("/^[+-]?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?$/", $data);
```

but not work I expected.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Are the individual fields seperated with spaces or NewLines???? i think @AvinashRaj confused the issue with his edit!!!

Comment: The originals values are in a string variable only separated for a sign possitive or negative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
$yourstring = "0+1.65+0.002-23.9";
$regex = '~\+|(?=-)~';
$splits = preg_split($regex, $yourstring);
print_r($splits);
```

Output (see [live php demo](http://ideone.com/UkhDMZ)):

```
[0] => 0
[1] => 1.65
[2] => 0.002
[3] => -23.9
```

**Explanation**

- Our regex is `+|(?=-)`. We will split on whatever it matches
- It matches `+`, OR `|`...
- the lookahead `(?=-)` matches a position where the next character is a `-`, allowing us to keep the `-`
- Then we split!

**Option 2 if you decide you also want to keep the `+` Character**

```
(?=[+-])
```

This regex is one lookahead that asserts that the next position is either a plus or a minus. For my sense of esthetics it's quite a nice solution to look at. :)

Output (see [online demo)](http://ideone.com/NjIzi9):

```
[0] => 0 
[1] => +1.65
[2] => +0.002
[3] => -23.9
```

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: FYI: Added live php demo :)

Comment: Wow, that was fast!! Thanks you very much.

Comment: There are a time limit for accept. In a few minutes I'll do XD. Repeat, Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks, Gopar! See you next time. :)

Answer (score 4):

You could try this

```
$data = ' 0 1.65 0.002 -23.9';
$t = str_replace( array(' ', ' -'), array(',',',-'), trim($data) );
$ta = explode(',', $t);

print_r($ta);
```

Which gives you an array containing each field like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1.65
    [2] => 0.002
    [3] => -23.9
)
```

RE: Your comment: *The originals values are in a string variable only separated for a sign possitive or negative*

```
$data = ' 0+1.65+0.002-23.9 ';

$t = str_replace( array('-', '+'), array(',-',',+'), trim($data) );
$ta = explode(',', $t);
print_r($ta);
```

which gives a similiar answer but with the correct inputs and outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => +1.65
    [2] => +0.002
    [3] => -23.9
)
```

Comment: This way you dont need to load the regex engine, quite an overhead,  for a fairly simple bit of text manipulation.